# Batch file to copy and rename the copied file

Tags: batch-file

I would like to create a batch file to copy *.EXT files to the destination folder with appended date and time to file name and copy upto maximum 30 files. After 30 files are copied, should delete oldest file. (while copy the 31st file, the 1st file should be deleted, and so on).

Thanks for your support. Have a great day!

Comment: What have you tried?  Hint: look into `forfiles /?`, paying special attention to the `@fdate` and `@ftime` command variables.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I have tried the below codes referring one of the posts here. It has two limitations, 1. it copies single file not all files with specified extensios. 2. It does not delete oldest nth file.

Comment: `@echo off
forfiles /p "M:\Meta" /s /m *.* /d -10 /c "cmd /c del @path"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('wmic OS Get localdatetime  ^| find "."') do set dt=%%a
set YYYY=%dt:~0,4%
set MM=%dt:~4,2%
set DD=%dt:~6,2%
set HH=%dt:~8,2%
set Min=%dt:~10,2%
set Sec=%dt:~12,2%

set stamp=%DD%-%MM%-%YYYY%_%HH%-%Min%-%Sec%`